# Why does a functioning ODBC connection fail after a few minutes (Excel VBA / Oracle)?

Tags: excel, database, oracle, odbc

I would greatly appreciate any feedback on this issue.

We are currently migrating our VBA tools to Windows 10  / Excel 2016. In our tools, we often connect to an Oracle DB, fetch data and process it in Excel.

Under Win10, I have chosen the following settings:

- ODBC Data Sources: Oraclein OraHome112_54 added, Connection test works
- Excel: References "Microsoft Office 16.0 Access db..." and "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1"
- Excel: variables, I declare "oCon as ADODB.Connection" and "oRs as ADODB.Recordset", both are set with "CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") and "Recordset" respectively
- Connection string: "DSN=DbName;User=12345;Password=xyz"

Now the issue: when starting up the workbook in a new Excel instance, I can run the relevant queries several times. Then after a couple of minutes (say 5-10 minutes), the code runs into the error "Run-time error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)': Catastrophic failure" when trying to connect to the database (before running the SQL Query).

I have tried to change the Connection string already to "Data Source=" instead of "DSN=" - same thing.

How can that be? First it works and then it stops. After shutting Excel and opening a new one, it works again for a couple of minutes.

Many thanks for your help on this one.

EDIT: I have now re-phrased the connection string to the "more modern" style, but it does not fix the issue.
Driver={Oracle in OraHome112_64};dbq=something.net:1522/something_else.net;UID=user123;PWD=pw123;

EDIT2: yet another variation of connection string, same issue:
strConn = "Provider=oraLEDB.Oracle.1;User ID=User123;Password=PW123;Data Source=something.net:1522/something_else.net"

Answer (score 0):

After restarting Excel and using the string under EDIT2, it turns out no more error. It has been running stable with this string for a few hours now.

Hopefully, this will help someone in the future, it took me around 10 hours to figure it out.